# Passing value from one <div> to another in a single page via POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

I have dynamically loaded a page. In that page I have two `div` with the required values or the data displayed in one `div` or `iframe` and the values passed using POST to another file that should reflect in another `div` or `iframe` as a result.

Please help me to solve this....
Thank you.

Following is my Sample code

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftbar" style="background-color:#eeeeee;width:400px;height:1000px;float:left;position:absolute;">
<iframe src="form1.html" width="1050px" height="1500px" seamless></iframe>
</div>
<div  id="container" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:1000px;width:990px;float:right;">
<iframe src="process.php" name="content" width="1050px" height="1500px" seamless></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

form1.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>

 <form name="myform" action="process.php" method="POST"  >
    <input type="hidden" name="check_submit" value="1" />

    Choose the colors:       <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Colors[]" value="green" checked="checked" onclick="document.forms.myform.submit();"/> Green<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Colors[]" value="yellow" onclick="document.forms.myform.submit();" /> Yellow             <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Colors[]" value="red" onclick="document.forms.myform.submit();"/> Red                    <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Colors[]" value="gray" onclick="document.forms.myform.submit();" /> Gray                 <br>
    <br /><br />


  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

process.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) {
        if (isset($_POST['Colors']) ) {
            $_POST['Colors'] = implode(', ', $_POST['Colors']);
        }
        echo "Colors you chose: {$_POST['Colors']}";
    }
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `main.html` to `main.php` and for form name instead of `process.php` just use `main.php`

```
<html >
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftbar" style="background-color:#eeeeee;width:400px;height:1000px;float:left;position:absolute;">
            <iframe src="form1.html" width="1050px" height="1500px" seamless></iframe>
        </div>

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['Colors'])) {
            if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) {
                $_POST['Colors'] = implode(', ', $_POST['Colors']);
            }
            echo "Colors you chose: {$_POST['Colors']}";

        <div  id="container" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:1000px;width:990px;float:right;">
            <iframe src="process.php" name="content" width="1050px" height="1500px" seamless>   </iframe>
        </div>

        <?PHP
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u for your response but its not working the same problem its displaying the result in the same div leftbar only but need to display at container its not happening

Comment: Did you changed your main.html to main.php?

Comment: if you are calling isset() and array_key_exists() and printing the choosen colors name in a main.php then what is the need of process.php.

Comment: From the beginning instead of 3 files if i keep all codes in a single  file then also its working perfectly.But due to heavy code i cant keep everything in single file so thought of dividing it.